# How to enable constructors in the new REMIX IDE or Truffle framework since MIST is depreciated

Tags: truffle, remix, mist, constructor

I used to dabble with making tokens and contracts and started to get back into it.

I liked the functionality that mist offered where you could input constructors values directly in mist. I can not seem to find a way to do this with remix IDE? How do I enable this option in Remix compiler or a maybe use a different development framework? What wallet are people using to compile and test code since MIST is no longer supported?

I used to just add my unsigned integers and then input the arguments later.
[image]